dependency between pydantic fields for validation
I have an issue validating input data to a pydantic model where there is a dependency between two fields. For example:
# these option tuples are generally pulled from a database before the Model is defined
options_v1 = ("a", "b", "c")
options_v2 = ("d", "e", "f")

class Model(BaseModel):
    version = int
    field = Literal[options_v1]  # how to allow for options_v2 if version is 2?

In this case, Model has a field, with a list of available options. I've recently added a version to this Model and the available list of options for field is different in version 2 than it is in version 1. Is there a clever way to define a model that has a dependency like this in pydantic?

It's worth noting that Model is a parent class to many other classes in my application and so it is pretty undesirable to create a second ModelV2 to manage this situation.


It depends. Do you need to be able to interpret both versions of the model in one python session? If not, you could do Literal[*options_v1] but I don't know if type checkers are happy with that.

If you need both, try something along Literal[*options_v1, *options_v2] and add a model_validator which does the validation you want.

Alternatively to the Literal type, you could create an Enum dynamically and use this as a type. Type checkers may like that more, idk.
